# Question about loadNibNamed:

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I implemented a loadNibNamed: method to awake some window.

A Window, that opened is not active. How can I make this window current, when is will loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[window makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];`